# phonegap window.plugins.googleplus not defined

Tags: cordova, google-plus

I have installed the cordova-plugin-googleplus from https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus and followed the directions to get it installed but when i call any of the methods I get an error that undefined has no method "isAvailable" (for example).

If I do a console.log on window.plugins I get an object back with one key - insomnia.

Not sure why googleplus isn't in there or if I have missed a step setting it up so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is Phonegap not serving 3rd party plugins over the "Phonegap Serve" developer app.  They don't support plugins that aren't pure JS.  This isn't actually an issue with the plugin but just my not understanding how the phonegap devleoper app worked with "Phonegap serve"